# Error al modificar una imagen PHP Y MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

**Tengo este código pero me tira este error...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**

```
<?php
session_start();

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "trigoyponque2017"); 
/*
$ruta    = $_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name'];
$destino = "../productos/".$_FILES['foto1']['name'];
copy($_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name'],$destino);
$foto  =$_FILES['foto1']['name'];
*/
foreach ($_POST['seleccion'] as $indice => $valor){
//Vamos a verificar si trae la opcion de eliminar o modificar
$opcion = substr ($_POST['seleccion'][$indice],0,-1); //extraemos la parte de la cadena que elimina y/o modifica
switch($opcion){
    case 'modifica':
    if($_FILES['foto1']['name'] == ""){
    $sql= "UPDATE producto SET titulo='".$_POST['titulo'][$indice]."', descripcion='".$_POST['descripcion'][$indice]."' WHERE id=".$_POST['id'][$indice];
    }else{
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id=".$_POST['id'].";");   
    while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
        unlink("../productos/".$reg['foto']);
    }
    $ruta    = "../productos/";
    opendir($ruta);
    $destino = $ruta.$_FILES['foto1']['name'];
    copy($_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name'],$destino);
    $foto   = $_FILES['foto1']['name']; 

    $sql = "UPDATE producto SET titulo='".$_POST['titulo'][$indice]."', descripcion='".$_POST['descripcion'][$indice]."', foto='".$foto[$indice]."' WHERE id=".$_POST['id'][$indice];
    }
    break;

    case 'elimina':
    $sql="DELETE FROM producto WHERE id=".$_POST['id'][$indice];
    break;
    default: echo "<center>NO HAY NADA SELECCIONADO</center>"; break;
}
}
echo "Variable sql: ".$sql;

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
if (!$resultado ){
     echo ("ERROR AL EJECUTAR LA CONSULTA");
}
else{
    echo "<center>FELICIDADES SENTENCIA EJECUTADA CORRECTAMENTE<br />
    <a href='editar_producto.php'><input type='button' value='Volver'></a></center>";
}


mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

**No sé porque no encuentra la ruta si ahí la estoy definiendo...**

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

Al parecer la *línea 19* que te indica en el primer **aviso** es:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id=".$_POST['id'].";");
```

veo que en linea anterior de UPDATE:

```
$sql= "UPDATE producto SET titulo='".$_POST['titulo'][$indice]."', descripcion='".$_POST['descripcion'][$indice]."' WHERE id=".$_POST['id'][$indice];
```

lo que hay `$_POST['id']` lo refieres con un valor de índice; aún aquí es un array `$_POST['id']` por que en tal caso es lo que te hace falta indicar como en el `UPDATE`.

Comment: Ya corregí esos errores, pero ahora no edita la imagen. No sé el porque no encuentra la ruta, si ahí la estoy definiendo. (?)

Comment: Actualiza, agrega o modifica la imagen o como mejor consideres para ver los mensajes que recibes; igual el código para poder aportarte sugerencias.